# Memoria para chat bot

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um chatbot, implementei algumas funções e gostaria de saber se tem como faze-lo salvar o que eu o ensinasse digitando a frase e depois digitando a resposta para quando eu fizesse a pergunta ele soubesse a resposta fiz desta forma porem não sei como fazer para salvar perguntas e resposta segue o código

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot
import os
from datetime import datetime
from googlesearch import search
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import wikipedia
import json

import webbrowser
wikipedia.set_lang('pt') #difinindo wikipedia para portugues

speaker = pyttsx3.init()

bot = ChatBot('Iana', read_only=True)

keywords = ['o que é','fale-me', 'quem é', 'quem foi','definição','defina']

google_keywords = ['pesquisar por', 'pesquise por','pesquise','tocar no']


dict_cmds = {}

def load_cmds():
    lines = open('cmds.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        parts = line.split('\t')
        dict_cmds.update({parts[0]: parts[1]})


# CHATBOT TRAINER..

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
for _file in os.listdir('Chats'):
    lines = open('Chats/' + _file, 'r').readlines()
    bot.train(lines)


def speak(text):
    speaker.say(text)
    speaker.runAndWait()


def evaluate(text): #passar um comando
    result = None
    try:
        result = dict_cmds[text]
    except:
        result = None
    return result
######## comandos externos######
def run_cmd(cmd_type):
    result = None

    if cmd_type == 'asktime':
        now = datetime.now()
        result = 'São' + str(now.hour) + 'horas e' + str(now.minute )+'minutos. '
    if cmd_type == 'askdate':
        now = datetime.now()
        months = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
        result  = 'Hoje é ' + str(now.day) + ' de ' + months[now.month - 1]
    if cmd_type =='bloco':
        now = os.startfile('notepad.exe')
        result = 'abrindo bloco de notas'
    if cmd_type == 'musica':
        now = os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\PreSonus\Studio One 3\Studio One.exe")
        result = 'um momento'
    if cmd_type == 'aprender':
        chave = input('digite uma frase: ')
        resp = input('digite a resposta: ')


    return result


def get_answer(text):
    result = None
    for key in keywords:
        if text.startswith(key):
            result = text.replace(key, '')


    if result is not None:
        results = wikipedia.search(result)
        result = wikipedia.summary(results[0],sentences=2)

    return  result

def search_web(text):
    result = None
    if text is not None:
        for key in google_keywords:
            if text.startswith(key):
                result = text.replace(key,'')

        if result is not None:
            for url in search(text, stop=3):
                webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                break
            return 'pesquisando por' + result.rstrip()
    return result


load_cmds()  # carrega os comandos



r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as s:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

    while True:
        try:
            audio = r.listen(s)
            speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt').lower()
            response = run_cmd(evaluate(speech))
            if response == None:
                response = get_answer(speech)
                if response == None:
                    response = search_web(speech)
                    if response == None:
                        response = bot.get_response(speech)
            print('Voce disse:{} '.format(speech))
            print('Bot: {} '.format(response))
            speak(response)
        except:
            print('Algum erro ocorreu.')
```

Comment: Pode usar Sqlite, firebird, ou até mesmo um banco de dados remoto, como mysql, postgre, sqlserver (de preferencia estes ultimos via API devido a segurança).

Comment: Gostei da idéia mas disse sou novo em python ainda estou aprendendo não sei como implementar isso no cod por me explicar